# PowerShell execution policy with VM Fleet benchmark

Tags: windows, powershell

Currently I have a 4-node S2D cluster, which we will be shipping to our client in a few days. I need to perform some storage benchmarks before, and previously I found an article about stress test – VM Fleet https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/deploy-vm-fleet-to-benchmark-your-storage-system.

Currently I’m trying to allow PowerShell to use the VM Fleet scripts, but get

> Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the
>   setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope

and there are no changes to policies made. Am I missing something?

Also, benchmark is performed on all of the cluster nodes, how can I choose for example 3 out of 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue, and I bet the script execution was configured by the domain group policy. Check the Group Policy Management on a domain controller (gpmc.msc)

Here’s more detailed explanation about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe/27753927

I guess it depends on the amount of CSVs, so if you have 3 CSV out of 4 hosts, there will be 3 servers. I’m not sure though.

Answer (score 3):

Q: Also, benchmark is performed on all of the cluster nodes, how can I choose for example 3 out of 4?

A: You can deploy VM Fleet on just pointed cluster nodes, there's no need to run simulated workload everywhere.